# Mongoose: updated properties of a new object are not detected

Tags: mongoose

I have a model with an array property inside.
I want to find and object inside this array, or create + push it if it does not exist yet.
Then I add a property to that object, and save the root object.
My new property is added only when the object already existed in the database. If it is a new object, all changes added AFTER it was added to the array are ignored.

```js
const user = await UserModel.findById(id).orFail()
let boardGame = user.boardGames.find((boardGame) => boardGame.id === boardGameId)
if (!boardGame) {
  boardGame = new BoardGame(boardGameId)
  user.boardGames.push(boardGame)
}
boardGame.someProperty = someValue // This is save in the database only if boardGame already existed
await user.save()
```

This code is simplified. I know I could solve if with "markModified" also but it seems ugly to do that all the time.
Instead of `new BoardGame(boardGameId)`, can I create the new subdocument with capability of tracking changes?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the trick: instead of using the object that is added inside the array, I must add the object inside the array then gather it back the extended version from the array.

It is explained in mongoose subdocument documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html (see "Adding Subdocs to Arrays").

My code finally looks like this:

```js
const user = await UserModel.findById(id).orFail()
let boardGame = user.boardGames.find((boardGame) => boardGame.id === boardGameId)
if (!boardGame) {
  user.boardGames.push(new BoardGame(boardGameId))
  boardGame = user.boardGames[user.boardGames.length - 1]
}
boardGame.someProperty = someValue
await user.save()
```